# Foursquare Button : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier due to quote in venue.html

Tags: javascript, button, share, foursquare

I'm trying to add a Foursquare button to my website but I've encountered a problem.
I've set up every field in the address, and when i try to push the share button, this is what i get:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
The problem is coming form the venue.html of Foursquare.
Here is the line:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUj18.png

It's clear the the quote "d'azur" is breaking everything but i can't do anything on this page, it's a 4sq page. 
Has anyone encountered that ? Or maybe any idea to fix it ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report. This is a bug and we have already pushed a fix for this, which you should be seeing shortly.

Comment: Hi ! Any news about it ? Thanks !